# How to properly create Prometheus metrics with unique field

Tags: spring, spring-boot, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have a system that regularly downloads files and parses them. However, sometimes something might go wrong with the parsing and I have the task to create a Prometheus alert for when a certain file fails. My
initial idea is to create a custom counter alert in Prometheus - something like

processed_files_total and use status as label because if the file fails it has FAILED status and if it succeeds - SUCCESS, so supposedly the alert should look like

increase(processed_files_total{status=FAILED}[24h]) > 0 and I hope that this will alert me in case there is at least 1 file with failed status.

The problem comes from the fact that I also want to have the
exact filename in the alert message and since each file has a unique name I'm almost sure that it is not a good idea to put it as label e.g. filename={filename} - According to Prometheus docs -
`Do not use labels to store dimensions with high cardinality (many different label values), such as user IDs, email addresses, or other unbounded sets of values.`
is there any other way I can achieve getting the filename from the alert or this is the way to go ?

Answer (score 1):

It's a good question.

I think the correct answer is that the alert should notify you that something failed and the resolution is to go to the app's logs to identify the specific file(s) that failed.

Lightning won't strike you for using the filename as a label value in Prometheus if you really must but, I think, as you are, using an unbounded value should give you pause as to whether you're *abusing* the tool.

Metrics seem intrinsically (hunch) about monitoring aggregate state (an unusual number of files are failing) rather than specific (why did this one fail); logs and tracing tools help with the specific cases.